# How many ways to choose a 5 player basketball team

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to choose $5$ players between $12$ players?
I know this part:

$C(12,5)$.

But part $b$ asks:
How many of our choices include strongest and weakest players?
And I don't know how to solve part $b$.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part (b) says: there are two people called *strongest* and *weakest*, and they must be on the team. The other three slots may be filled by any of the "middle" ten players, so the answer is $\binom{10}3$.